# Do any countries vote for representatives non-geographically?

Tags: voting-systems

In the United States, we vote for the president representing our country, two senators representing our state, a US representative from our district, and various state and local representatives based on local laws. These people all represent a geographic location. This leads to various problems like gerrymandering and some demographics getting poorly represented.

Are there any representative democracies that elect representatives another way?

I can imagine lots of other equally good or worse ways- individuals are represented by race, class, profession, etc. I can also imagine an option where you self select- one votes for a party that represents his/her interests, then the parties individually decide how to select candidates. Have any of these things been tried?

Comment: Are you asking specifically for separation into constituencies by another criteria than location of residence or no separation at all? Because the latter [is actually a very common system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Party-list_proportional_representation).

Comment: In New Zealand: [Māori electorates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C4%81ori_electorates)

Comment: I do not know of the details to provide an answer (are seats allocated really on a religious basis, or is it that districting is done along religious lines?), but Lebanon is worth a look at.

Comment: I've no time to write a full answer, but you should check Elections in Lebanon: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elections_in_Lebanon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Australia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system_of_Australia) uses a variant of a system called [single transferable vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_transferable_vote) for its Senate (and a variant of [instant-runoff voting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant-runoff_voting) for its lower house, but that's still geographic districts).

[Germany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electoral_system_of_Germany) uses a system with geographic districts, but it also makes the system proportional by awarding bonus seats (unassociated with geographic districts) to parties that receive a higher share of the vote than their share of the seats.

A number of countries use some form of [proportional representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_representation) where parties receive a number of seats proportional to their share of the vote.

> I can also imagine an option where you self select- one votes for a party that represents his/her interests, then the parties individually decide how to select candidates.

This is called [closed party-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_list) and is rather common actually.  There are nineteen countries that use that system for at least one of their houses.  And a number of other countries that use similar but different systems ([open party-list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_list), [mixed member proportional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-member_proportional_representation), etc.).

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

France had a parliament (French National Assembly of 1789) where representatives were by class. That's where "left" and "right" label originated.

Britain has [votes in The City of London](http://French%20National%20Assembly) - not to be confused with London the city - that come from companies headquartered there.

A whole list of such examples can be found in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reserved_political_positions

Answer (score 2):

Belgium elects 21 MEPs to the European Parliament, and they are divided into three constituencies based on language.  12 MEPs represent the Dutch-speaking electoral college, 8 represent the French-speaking electoral college, and 1 represents the German-speaking electoral college.  While in any given area the majority of people will vote in the same electoral college, in the larger cities such as Brussels people have the choice of which electoral college to vote in.

Comment: For me this is very misleading: the place where you live and not your language does decide for whom you can vote.